# weighing the maximum likelihood

Tags: chi-squared-test, maximum-likelihood, weighted-regression

I would like to define a log-likelihood (starting with a gaussian distribution) for an observed value of a quantity ($x_i$), compared to the measured value based on a given model ($\hat{x_i}$) and instead of using the measurement errors for each observation ($\sigma_i$), I would like to use the weighing value which is a combination of errors and another measured parameter, i.e. $w_i = 1/(\sigma_i^2+\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ can be a given constant value. It is easy to show that $w_i$ has reverse property as error, meaning it is higher for values with smaller errors mostly.

How could I re-write the likelihood and use the weight value for each measurement instead of errors?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have observations comprising normal distribution with parameters $x, \sigma^2 + \alpha$.  You have model predictions $\hat x, \hat \sigma^2$.  Typically, when people don't mention $\hat \sigma^2$, they're just fixing it at one.  Then, rather than a log-likelihood, you want its generalization, the cross entropy.

It also sounds like you were thinking of weighting the components of the log-likelihood (or cross entropy) by some $w_i$.  Do this only if $w_i$ represents missingness, which it doesn't in your definition.

Comment: so I should look for the `cross entropy`, to find the definition of my likelihood? Usually in my field of research they do it since the signal is very low and also decrease with many parameters. I saw the formalism in the literature when they bin the data and estimate the quantities in bins but I don't want to do binning the data and I don't know how it changes?!

Comment: can you please elaborate more how **the cross entropy** can be related to my application? I also found this [paper](http://www.desy.de/~blobel/mlmethod.ps), page 20.

Comment: @dalek: Just write out the cross entropy in terms of your parameters.   That's your likelihood.

Comment: Can you please introduce a reference for the cross entropy method which would be close to the application I am looking for?

Comment: @Dalek: The cross entropy is just an expectation over the log-likelihood you had before given that your observations are uncertain.

Comment: well Neil, the terminology of the cross-entropy was absolutely new to me, so I will appreciate if you give an example how the log-likelihood should be written in the framework of the cross-entropy.

Comment: @Dalek: If you had an observation x, and a prediction $P$ with parameters $\hat x, \hat \sigma$, then your log-likelihood is $-\log f(x \mid \hat x, \hat \sigma)$ where $f$ is a Gaussian density.  The cross entropy $H^\times(D; P)$ is just $E_{x\sim D}(-\log f(x \mid \hat x, \hat \sigma))$ where $D$ is the observed *distribution*.

Comment: thanks for the formalism. I am wondering whether you can join chat, because I still have some statistical questions and I will appreciate if you could help.

Comment: @dalek: sorry, am very busy today. Maybe ask another question?